# Is a question with answers in multiple languages necessarily too broad?

Tags: discussion

I was looking at this question, which does theoretically have several correct answers, because the asker doesn't limit the scope much. So they could be asking for answers in any language (although there's essentially a canonical answer to it).

Here's the full question, which was never edited:

---

#### [Menu that takes up 100% of screen on mobile, but not desktop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47020180/menu-that-takes-up-100-of-screen-on-mobile-but-not-desktop)

> So this is more of a general question for web design.
>
> Let's assume I wanted to build a hamburger menu that when active, takes up 25% the width of a desktop screen, but 100% the width of a mobile screen.
>
> How is this achievable?

---

It actually seems like the question is asking something very specific: How can you make something that "takes up 25% the width of a desktop screen, but 100% the width of a mobile screen."

I don't really care about this particular question, I'm more thinking of it as a case study. I'm curious about how the "too broad" category is used in practice.

Comment: It's... not exactly narrow....

Comment: You could post a comment, referring him to ux.stackexchange.com.  Admittedly I don't get the "multiple languages" angle.

Comment: The weirdly apologetic comment at the beginning makes it sound like it would belong there, but it definitely seems like it's a "how do I technically" question, which seems more like it belongs on SO.

Comment: I mean. The close vote reason for too broad says something about 'too many possible answers'. If there are multiple ways to achieve this (multiple languages to get the behavior) how is that not too broad? The OP hasn't specified their problem enough

Comment: @HansPassant Please don't suggest the UX site because implementation questions are [off-topic](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1393/83293) there.

Comment: Not necessarily, but usually (almost always). This specific example certainly is too broad. It also doesn't demonstrate any research effort. In general, it is rare that a question doesn't have a language tag. More often you see these too-broad questions tagged with several languages.

Comment: How is this a question about multiple languages?  It's a question about HTML and CSS.  Yes, you can ask questions about usign HTML and CSS...